# How to move Jenkins towards IAAC?

Tags: jenkins, devops, infrastructure

We have got an old style Jenkins environment administration  and managing Jobs using GUI . We are interested to move towards Infrastructure as a code. Could you please advise me on the transition plan and new tools required for this migration.

Any advise to choose between Jenkins builtin DSL or Groovy script to create pipelines?

Cheers,
Joseph

Answer (score 0):

Write Declarative style Jenkins Pipeline
its easy and faat ro convert to IAC  for jenkins job configuration.
I have mentioned link for your reference

https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/